# Clicking a download link in Safari causes all target=_blank links to download when clicked, is there a workaround?

Tags: html, hyperlink, download, safari

**Issue:**
After clicking on a link that downloads content, all other links that have target="_blank" and no download attr download when clicked instead of opening in the new tab.

**Browser:**
Safari 11.0.2

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h3>Instructions</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Click <a href='sample.txt' target='_blank'>ME</a> (download NOT present) to see page load in new tab then come back to this page</li>
      <li>Click <a href='sample.txt' download='sample.txt'>ME</a> (download PRESENT) to see it downloaded</li>
      <li>Click <a href='sample.txt' target='_blank'>ME</a> (download NOT present).  Safari forces this link to download</li>
    </ul>
  </body>

</html>
```

**Code Sample:**
https://embed.plnkr.co/IscC6LTTmpEbAMLrxyYJ/

**Replicate:**

1. Click a link with download attribute
2. After the download click a link on the same page with target="_blank" and see that it's forced to download instead of opening in a new tab.

**Update:**
I updated the issue hopefully to explain better what's happening.  I've found a sort of workaround, but if I change the links to _self instead of _blank then they work like normal after a download.

Comment: Though the bounty on this prevents close or flag votes, I don't feel this post follows the SO question guidelines. It's not clear what's being asked, and I'm not sure the question belongs on this site

Comment: I think it may be an 'agressive' caching problem (caching the HTTP response headers, perhaps).  But I don't have Safari to test with.  Have you tried giving each `href` a query parameter just to rule this out?  E.g `href='sample.txt?newtab'` and `href='sample.txt?download'`.  If both URLs have different query strings, the server will ignore the query strings but the browser will consider them to be different resources and cache them separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really an answer, but after reporting the issue to apple and waiting, we now have Safari 11.1.1 which seems to have resolved the issue, so marking resolved.

Answer (score 7):

With regards to your issue mention above, you have a couple of option to download a file:

**Open file in same window:**

```
<a href="sample.txt" target="_self">Click to Download</a>
```

**Open file in new window:**

```
<a href="sample.txt" target="_blank">Click to Download</a>
```

**Force file download window:**
*However, if you want to force the file to download, by prompting a download pop-up box (to open or save), then all you need to do is add ‘download’ to the  link as seen below:*

```
<a href="sample.txt" download>Click to Download</a>
```

Therefore, your edited code could look something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h3>Instructions</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Click <a href='sample.txt' target='_blank'>ME</a> (download NOT present) to see page load in new tab then come back to this page</li>
      <li>Click <a href='sample.txt' download='sample.txt'>ME</a> (download PRESENT) to see it downloaded</li>
      <li>Click <a href='sample.txt' download>ME</a> (download NOT present).  Safari forces this link to download</li>
    </ul>
  </body>

</html>
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: I agree the new tab must have opened and vanished within a fraction of time.

Comment: Does Safari render text documents natively in the browser, or does it always force them to be downloaded? Try this link for example: https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1123.txt (loads in Chrome)

Comment: -1: I don't think you read the question carefully.  The question is "why do the NON download links cause the browser to download after using the download link".   The question already demonstrates the knowledge contained in this answer.  The problem is specific to Safari.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't what I was looking for.  I already know how to make something download.  the problem is that when you have a link that does a download, after that other links that you don't want to download (so no download attr) download anyways instead of opening in the new tab